# How to make a checkbox be in a box and have text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create three hidden check boxes so when you click on each box new information appears below it.

Right now I have 3 check boxes: Click1, Click2, Click3. Each word you click on opens text below it (respectively named Content1, Content2, Content3).

Is there a way to make each Click text be in boxes? So you're clicking more of a box with text in it than just that plain text.

Here's my codepen:
http://codepen.io/arielelliott/pen/XmwBaP

HTML:

```
<label for="box1">Click1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="box1" name="demo">
<label for="box2">Click2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="box2" name="demo">
<label for="box3">Click3</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="box3" name="demo">
<div class="new1"><p>Content1</p></div>
<div class="new2"><p>Content2</p></div>
<div class="new3"><p>Content3</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Default State */
body{
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.new1, .new2, .new3{
  display: none;
}

/* Checkbox */
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display:none;
  visibility:hidden;
}

/* Toggled State */
input[type=checkbox]#box1:checked ~ div.new1{
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
input[type=checkbox]#box2:checked ~ div.new2 {
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
input[type=checkbox]#box3:checked ~ div.new3 {
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
input[type=checkbox]#box1 ~ div.new2 {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]#box2 ~ div.new1 {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]#box3 ~ div.new1, div.new2 {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I made this, let me know if you want to use it and I will make it specifically tailored for you http://jsfiddle.net/www139/wpq6qjyf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in many ways with different CSS properties: `border`, `padding`, `width`, `height`...

I just added a few of them to your CSS and a also added a class to style the labels (`toggle-control`) as you should try to avoid using element selectors when possible.

Note that I changed the order of the labels and checkboxes so that the checkboxes go before the label that will trigger them. This way you can also style the label depending on the checkbox state.

```css
/* Default State */

body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font: normal .75rem/100% Sans-Serif;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

p + p {
  margin: .5rem 0 0 0;
}

/* Pane */

.pane {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: .25rem 0;
  padding: .5rem;
  text-align: justify;
}

/* Checkbox */

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* Toggled State */

#box1:checked ~ #pane1,
#box2:checked ~ #pane2,
#box3:checked ~ #pane3 {
  display: block;
}

/* Toggle Control */

.toggle-control {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 .25rem .25rem 0;
  background: #50F;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: .5rem 1rem .5rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 .25rem 1rem -.5rem #000;
  border: 1px solid #20C;
  transition: box-shadow ease-in .125s;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.toggle-control:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 .0 1rem -.5rem #000;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + .toggle-control:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: .5rem;
  height: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid #20C;
  left: .75rem;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -.25rem 0 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .toggle-control:before {
  background: #FEF;
  border: 1px solid #60F;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #FFF;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="box1" name="demo[]">
<label class="toggle-control" for="box1">Show 1</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="box2" name="demo[]">
<label class="toggle-control" for="box2">Show 2</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="box3" name="demo[]">
<label class="toggle-control" for="box3">Show 3</label>

<div class="pane" id="pane1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<div class="pane" id="pane2">
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
</div>

<div class="pane" id="pane3">
  <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
</div>
```

If you were using JavaScript to show the content then it would be possible to remove the `id` and `for` attributes on the checkboxes and labels, respectively, as you could just put the checkboxes inside the labels ([implicit labels](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1)).

Comment: Thank you!! This is just what I was looking to do! I don't know why I didn't think of styling the label. I appreciate your detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can style the labels however you like to make them more box-like. For example I just added this CSS to what you already had:

```
label {
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  border:2px solid #999;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}
label:hover {
  background: #666;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```css
/* Default State */

body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.new1,
.new2,
.new3 {
  display: none;
}
/* Checkbox */

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
/* Toggle Style */

.style {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 10px 0 0 50px;
  width: 200px;
}
/* Toggled State */

input[type=checkbox]#box1:checked ~ div.new1 {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
input[type=checkbox]#box2:checked ~ div.new2 {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
input[type=checkbox]#box3:checked ~ div.new3 {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
input[type=checkbox]#box1 ~ div.new2 {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]#box2 ~ div.new1 {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]#box3 ~ div.new1,
div.new2 {
  display: none;
}
label {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius:8px;
}
label:hover {
  background: #666;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<label for="box1">Click1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="box1" name="demo">
<label for="box2">Click2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="box2" name="demo">
<label for="box3">Click3</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="box3" name="demo">
<div class="new1">
  <p>Content1</p>
</div>
<div class="new2">
  <p>Content2</p>
</div>
<div class="new3">
  <p>Content3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest answer would be to style the label element. I used the wildcard with teh for attribute in case you want to restrict this from affecting other label elemnst on the page, and I added a cursor:pointer rule and hover state so it behaves more like what I think you're trying to acheive.

```
/*Label*/
label[for*='box']{
border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding:1em;
  margin:1em;
  display:inline-block;
  background: orange;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label[for*='box']:hover{
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add styles to the `label` element (and if you like, you can add `label:hover` styles too):

```css
body{
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.new1, .new2, .new3{
  display: none;
}

/* Checkbox */
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display:none;
  visibility:hidden;
}

/* Toggled State */
input[type=checkbox]#box1:checked ~ div.new1{
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
input[type=checkbox]#box2:checked ~ div.new2 {
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
input[type=checkbox]#box3:checked ~ div.new3 {
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
input[type=checkbox]#box1 ~ div.new2 {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]#box2 ~ div.new1 {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]#box3 ~ div.new1, div.new2 {
  display: none;
}

label {
display: inline-block;
margin: 6px;
padding: 6px;
font-weight: bold;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
border-top: 2px solid rgba(191, 0, 0, 1);
border-right: 2px solid rgba(95, 0, 0, 1);
border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(95, 0, 0, 1);
border-left: 2px solid rgba(191, 0, 0, 1);
background-color: rgba(127, 0, 0, 1);
}

label:hover {
border-top: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 191, 1);
border-right: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 95, 1);
border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 95, 1);
border-left: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 191, 1);
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 127, 1);
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="box1">Click1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="box1" name="demo">
<label for="box2">Click2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="box2" name="demo">
<label for="box3">Click3</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="box3" name="demo">
<div class="new1"><p>Content1</p></div>
<div class="new2"><p>Content2</p></div>
<div class="new3"><p>Content3</p></div>
```